# mp audio stops playing after certain amount of plays

Tags: java, android, xml, audio, mp3

I have a button that plays an mp3, but after too many clicks, the mp3 doesn't start anymore. I'm guessing this has something to do with memory running out, so how do you destroy the mp after each play is finished?

```
if (mp != null) {
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                    }
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fart6);
                    mp.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this

```
 mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.stop();
                            mp.release();

                        }
                    });
```